# Is it possible to install nodejs on ubuntu server 20.04 on a virtual machine?

Tags: node.js, npm, apt, ubuntu-20.04, ubuntu-server

I'm having trouble installing NodeJs and NPM on Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a Virtual Machine. The "unpacking" process takes forever and I don't remember it taking a long time when installing it on my physical computer (running on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04). I want to know if it is possible or why is it taking too long? Are the system requirements for my vm a problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

To answer this it would be good to have more details. Which package are you trying to install? What are the specs of your vm?

Also I think this should belong in the [Linux & Unix Stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).